# how to create download link of animated images

Tags: javascript, html, css, download, marquee

Recently I was create animated image in html with SPAN ans Marquee tag. And now I want to create download link for this images, but I don't know how to do this? Please anyone help me...

This is my [Online Project](http://ebookchoise.protricks.in/)

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <title> Marquee </title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   
<body>

<div id="figure">
  <img src="a.jpg" name="images"/>
  <div class="figcaption">
    <span>
     <h2> Believe In Your Self!!!</h2>
      <span class='spacer'></span>
      <br />
      <span class='spacer' align='right'></span>
      <h3><marquee>By: Ajay Rathod</marquee></h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
h3
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
   color: white;
    background: black; /* fallback */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: .5em;
}
#figure { 
  position: relative; 
}
#figure img { 
    display: block; /* removes trailing whitespace */
    outline: solid #000 1px;
    width:100%;
} 
.figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 501px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }
.figcaption span h2{
     color: white;
    background: black; /* fallback */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: .5em;

    &.spacer {
      padding: 0 5px;
      background: transparent;

    &::before { content: " "; } 
        }
.figcaption span h3{
    color: white;
    background: black; /* fallback */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: .5em;

    &.spacer {
      padding: 0 5px;
      background: transparent;

    &::before { content: " "; } 

    }
```

Comment: You can actually use them to have a lot of jquery plugin about it

Answer (score 0):

You can make any image as downloadable link by doing this

```
<a download="name.jpg" href="Image-Path" title="Image-Name">
 <img src="a.jpg" name="images"/>
</a>
```

Refer to this [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for browser compatibility